# load an already trained custom model : SPACY

Tags: python, spacy

I'm working with spacy on a named entity recognition model (ner). Here's the code for a basic model with 2 training sentences:

```
  

ner = nlp.create_pipe('ner')


labels = ['BOY', 'GIRL']
for label in labels:
    ner.add_label(label)





TRAIN_DATA = [
    ("Who is John ? He is lost", {"entities": [(7, 11, "BOY")]}),
    ("I like Lara. She likes you too", {"entities": [(7, 11, "GIRL")]}),
]
examples = []
for text, annots in TRAIN_DATA:
    examples.append(Example.from_dict(nlp.make_doc(text), annots))

for i in range(40):
    random.shuffle(examples)
    for batch in minibatch(examples,size=10):
        nlp.update(batch)
text = "Where is Sara. She is likes you ?"
doc = nlp(text)
for ent in doc.ents:
    print(ent.text, ent.label_)
```

Then I save my model for later use.

```
nlp.to_disk('Test') #save
spacy.load('./Test')
```

Unfortunately when loading my custom template I get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[72], line 2
      1 nlp.to_disk('Test') #save
----> 2 spacy.load('./Test')

File c:\Users\...\venv\Lib\site-packages\spacy\__init__.py:54, in load(name, vocab, disable, enable, exclude, config)
     30 def load(
     31     name: Union[str, Path],
     32     *,
   (...)
     37     config: Union[Dict[str, Any], Config] = util.SimpleFrozenDict(),
     38 ) -> Language:
     39     """Load a spaCy model from an installed package or a local path.
     40 
     41     name (str): Package name or model path.
   (...)
     52     RETURNS (Language): The loaded nlp object.
     53     """
---> 54     return util.load_model(
     55         name,
     56         vocab=vocab,
     57         disable=disable,
     58         enable=enable,
     59         exclude=exclude,
...
    191     err = f"Attempt to change dimension '{name}' for model '{self.name}' from {old_value} to {value}"
--> 192     raise ValueError(err)
    193 self._dims[name] = value

ValueError: Attempt to change dimension 'nV' for model 'hashembed' from 2000 to 5000
Output is truncated. View as a scrollable element or open in a text editor. Adjust cell output settings.
```

Why do I have this and not on a blank model where when I save it everything works fine.

How can I use this customized template?